# matrix multiplication using thread where each thread compute a row

Tags: c

1. hello guys , i wrote the below code for matrix multiplication using thread,
   thus each thread should compute a row then when i run that code it
   gives me the correct result for the first row ONLY and the other
   rows most of their elements are zeros. the martix size of M*M !! i can't find where the mistake is !!Thanks in advance

   ```
           # include <stdio.h>
           # include <pthread.h>
           # include <stdlib.h>
           #include <sys/time.h>
           int M;
           int A [100][100];

           int B [100][100];
           int C [100][100];

           struct v {
              int i; /* row */
              int j; /* column */
           };

           void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */
   ```

   ---

   ```
           int main()
           {
           clock_t cstart = clock();
             clock_t cend = 0;
              int count=0;
              pthread_t tid;    
               int iCount,jCount,kCount;
           printf("Enter The Size: \n");
           scanf("%d",&M);
           for(iCount=0;iCount<M;iCount++)
               {
                   for(jCount=0;jCount<M;jCount++)
                   {
                       printf("Enter Mat1[%d][%d] :",iCount,jCount);
                       scanf("%d",&A[iCount][jCount]);
                   }
               }
           for(iCount=0;iCount<M;iCount++)
               {
                   for(jCount=0;jCount<M;jCount++)
                   {
                       printf("Enter Mat2[%d][%d] :",iCount,jCount);
                       scanf("%d",&B[iCount][jCount]);
                   }
               }
            for(iCount = 0; iCount < M; iCount++) {
                    struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
                    data->i = iCount;
                    data->j = jCount;
                    pthread_t tid;       
                    pthread_attr_t attr; 
                    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
                    pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,&C[iCount]);
                    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
                    count++;
              }
             printf("\n Matrix 1 \n");

               for(iCount=0;iCount<M;iCount++)
               {
                   for(jCount=0;jCount<M;jCount++)
                   {
                       printf("%d \t",A[iCount][jCount]);
                   }
                   printf("\n");
               }    

               printf("\n Matrix 2 \n");

               for(iCount=0;iCount<M;iCount++)
               {
                   for(jCount=0;jCount<M;jCount++)
                   {
                       printf("%d \t",B[iCount][jCount]);
                   }
                   printf("\n");
               } 

           printf("\n Multipication of Matrices ...\n");
              for(iCount = 0; iCount < M; iCount++) {
                 for(jCount = 0; jCount < M; jCount++) {
                    printf("%d \t", C[iCount][jCount]);
                 }
                 printf("\n");
              }
           cend = clock();
             printf ("it took %.3f cpu sec\n", ((double)cend - (double)cstart)* 1.0e-6);
           return 0;

         }
   ```

   ---

   ```
           void *runner(void *param) {
              struct v *data = param; 
              int n, sum = 0; 
              int jCount;
           do{sum=0;
              for(n = 0; n< M; n++){
                 sum += A[data->i][n] * B[n][data->j];
              }
              C[data->i][data->j] = sum;

           data->j++;
           }while(data->j<M);
              pthread_exit(0);
           }
   ```

   ---

   ```
      // compile code : gcc thread.c -o out -pthread
     //                 ./out
   ```

Comment: I can't really help your problem, but if it is intended for real production use, think about one of the highly optimized libs. They know about cache size and so on. Is there still ATLAS / BLAS out there?

Comment: @ryyker: not really an issue here: the source matrices are only read by the different threads, not written, and the destination matrix cells computed by the different threads are disjoint.  Furthermore, the threads are not even run concurrently in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here in the thread creation loop:

```
data->j = jCount;
```

You should initialize `data->j` to `0`.  Instead you initialize it to jCount whose value is `M` at the end of the matrix initialization phase.  `data->j` does not make sense as a thread argument as each thread computes a whole column.

Answer (score 0):

You `malloc()` a `struct v` but then do nothing with it.

```
 struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
```

You pass the address of the nth row of the `C` 2-dimensional array to the thread you create:

```
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,&C[iCount]);
```

But the thread treats the address as a `struct v *`:

```
struct v *data = param;
```

Also, there's no point in starting a separate thread and then immediately waiting for it to finish:

```
         pthread_attr_init(&attr);
         pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,&C[iCount]);
         pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

Start **all** your threads in that loop, storing the `tid` in an array, then run another loop that joins them.